# Android beta testing and privacy

Tags: android, google-play

How do I invite users to beta test an app without compromising their privacy?

As far as I know, if I invite them to a **Google+** Community and/or a Google Group, their presence is essentially public to the rest of that community or group. Ideally I am looking for the ability to invite individuals privately via their email address, and with no unwanted publicity.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct. In order to beta test via Google Play, the user will be "known" to others in the test group to the extent of the personally identifying information provided by their Google account.

We use Hockey for beta testing our Android apps and other platforms, such as Mac and iOS. Relatively cheap service and beta users only need to enter in name and email. That info can be easily anonymized and is harder to correlate identity when compared to a Google account.

http://hockeyapp.net/features/